# Add sidebar in inner pages

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I am new to wordpress coding. I want to add a sidebar to pages other than the home page, both pages are my custom templates. I want to list in admin so that admin can edit the content of sidebar.

Also, do I need to create widget to display every side bar?

Comment: There are many good tutorials on the internet about this subject, also a lot of questions on this site. You can also start by looking at the codex on how to register sidebars and creating custom widgets. Thank you

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have just added a side bar any how, but i need to add some list(like module 1, module 2) in it, how would i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered many times already on this site.

There's 2 simple steps:

**One:** Add to functions file

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'         => __( 'Your Sidebar' ),
    'id'           => 'wpsites-sidebar',
    'description'  => __( 'Your Sidebar Description.' ),
    'before_title' => '<h1>',
    'after_title'  => '</h1>',
) );
```

**Two:** Add where you want to output sidebar

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'wpsites-sidebar' ) ) : ?>
    <ul class="wpsites-sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'wpsites-sidebar' ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For further learning, look in the [Twenty Fourteen default theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen) to see how its done.

[`register_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)
[`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)